# BPEL Transactions getting STUCK often in Weblogic SOA

Tags: soa, weblogic11g, bpel

We are really having a tough time recovering the BPEL transactions manually that are getting stuck in SOA often.. What could be the possible reason for that ? Why is it getting stuck often? We are using 11g.

Comment: You need to give more information than this... what errors are you seeing? What are your settings? It is impossible to answer a question like this with so little detail

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Bpel database adapters? Perheaps there are problems with the datasource.

Or are you accessing web services?

Did you tried to use Bpel Fault Policies?
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/dev.1111/e10224/bp_faults.htm#SOASE478

It provides 6 options:

ora-retry

ora-terminate

ora-human-intervention

ora-rethrow-fault

ora-replay-scope

ora-java